# How to debug performace issues with Maven

Tags: performance, java-8, maven-3

I'm observing serious issues with my maven build an I have no idea how to get root cause of this. Usually build takes 2-3 minutes, however quite often it takes more than 2 hours.

Launching clean install in debug mode didn't point any exceptions or issues, also transfer rate from repo for artifacts is pointing similar values in both cases.

I can see that execution hangs for long on modules compilation:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ tdskit-standardmodel ---
```

I checked also thread dump, no blocked thread in printout.

I'm using java jdk1.8.0_112 and maven 3.3.9

If anyone have any idea where to search for solutoin I'll be gratefull for hints.

Thanks

Comment: could it be that you are hitting this? https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8151267  Can you try jdk 7 or/and 9?

Comment: Perhaps, however in this bug problem can be reproduced every time, in my case sometimes there is no problem. JDK 7 is not an option but I guess it's worth to check 9